# CSS Sprite Background Repeat-x issue

Tags: css, sprite

I have created a CSS sprite with images of multiple sizes. This sprite is 100px in width and within it I have an image used for a star rating system that has a 25px width. I need to repeat it in the X direction. But when I set `repeat-x`, the sprite repeats according to it's whole width.

How can I set it up so that it only repeats the 25px X 25px star image inside it ?

Comment: Please try to explain the issue and/or how do you expect it to be in the end, with code and/or images.

Comment: If you've something code to show, It would be great.

Comment: .sprite { background: url('../images/sprite-image2.png') no-repeat top left; width: 137px; height: 24px;  } 
.sprite.sprite-image { background-position: 0 0; width: 271px; height: 288px; } 
.sprite.star { background-position: 0 -400px; width: 25px; height: 75px; } 
.sprite.red-bullet { background-position: 0 -485px; width: 7px; height: 7px; } I want .sprite.star to repeat

Comment: @SusanRaj - Please do not comment your code. Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: @SusanRaj - Do you mean you want the CSS property `background-repeat` with the value `repeat-x`?

Comment: Outside of having that star in a 25px sprite you should just repeat the element that it is the background of. Your browser will only fetch the image once anyways that is the whole point of sprites.